# Change app sub-menu/folder style to iPhone-style

Tags: cyanogenmod, launcher, home-screen, home-screen-folders

On the "desktop" of my phone, I can move my apps into folders together by dragging one on top of the other. However, as opposed to the iPhone (where they form a reduced-sized grid), the apps gets combined into a folder where I can no longer identify each of them. Is there some way to change this sub-menu/folder style to replicate the iPhone's functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve iPhone like sub folder view by downloading any launcher. Here is the link which you will find helpful
 [GO Launcher -Theme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&hl=en).

If you are interested in making it replicate iPhone's theme as well, then you will have to download additional theme which are compatible with Go Launcher app. Similar case goes if you download other themes.

The folder view in GO Launcher shows only 4 apps at a glance by default whereas iPhone shows 9 apps in a folder.

So in case you need the folder to preview 9 apps.Try downloading [LineLauncher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.campmobile.launcher) and follow these steps to achieve it:

- Download the [Line Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.campmobile.launcher).
- Set Line Launcher as homescreen.
- Go to preferences->Folder/Icon ->click on Preview of the folder icon.
- Select Thumbnail 3x3.